# Module not found: no module named numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pip

How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'" but I've already install it in pycharm. But it is not working in IDLE. What should I do?

Comment: Do you use the same version of Python in PyCharm and IDLE? PyCharm tends to use virtual environments (which is good) but in that case `numpy` might only have been installed in this virtual environment.

Comment: Yes my Idle and python has a version of 3.8.5. But IDLE cannot detetch the numpy I installed

Comment: Do you also have a Python 2.x on your system? Sometimes `pip` is `pip` for Python 2, and for Python 3 you have to use `pip3`.

Comment: The same version of Python doesn't mean that they use the same environment.

Answer (score -1):

Idle and pycharm are seperate virtual environments. You need to install numpy in both of them individually.
For your idle, you need to go to the command prompt/terminal and install numpy there

Comment: I already installed it in command prompt and it says that "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\---

Comment: Is your idle set up correctly? Can you import other modules installed?

Comment: IDLE and pycharm are IDEs, not environments. You can choose which environment the IDE should use.

Comment: Do you know what IDE stands for?